# opentype.js export font from canvas

Tags: javascript, download, html5-canvas, opentype

I am using `https://opentype.js.org/` to manipulate fonts on a canvas and I would like to download the changed font as an `.otf` file for further use.

The instructions to load and write a font (https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js) are kind of confusing and when using the `font.download()` function, it downloads the font I uploaded without any changes.

Is there an easy way to export/download the font from the canvas? or is there a way to parse the paths on the canvas back to binary or `.otf` file?

Comment: If the instructions for an open source project are unclear, step one is to ask the people who work on that open source project to update the documentation so that it's clearer. They have a public issue tracker, so: please, ask them. Doing so does not just help you, right now, but solves the problem for _everyone, from now on_, which is something that Stackoverflow cannot do.